# Problem with delay()

Tags: jquery

My requirement is to execute some code after some amount of time..Here is my code but it is not working, Might be some problem with my code..

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $.doTimeout(300,function() 
{
 $('xxxButton').trigger();
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doTimeout isn't a function. You want:

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('xxxButton').trigger();
    }, 300);
});
```

`$(function(){});` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){});` btw

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me know. I haven't heard of that plugin before.

Answer (score 1):

```
Using setTimeout

$(document).ready(function()
{    
setTimeout( function() {
        $('xxxButton').trigger('click');
    }, 300 );

);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) function in jQuery requires an argument to tell jQuery which event type you want to trigger. I'd guess that you have a button of some sort with an `id` attribute of `xxxButton` and you want to click it, if so, then you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.doTimeout(300, function() {
        $('#xxxButton').click();
    });
});
```

You could also use `$('#xxxButton').trigger('click')` if you really want to use `trigger`.